# ORACLE - UPDATE using INSERT seq inside FORALL

Tags: database, oracle

I have an ORACLE DB.
I'm trying to loop through an array using FORALL and inside that FORALL to insert into a table with TABLE.NEXTVAL and after that to update a foreign key of another table with the new TABLE.CURVAL but I know that it's impossible.

How can I implement it?

```
FORALL I IN 1 ..5
insert into tbl
    values (tbl_seq.NEXTVAL)
update foo set tbl_fk = tbl_seq.CURVAL where foo.id=I
```

Thanks

Comment: Your  `INSERT`  itself will not work anyway because dml statement without bulk binding cannot be used inside `FORALL`

Answer (score 1):

@Dvir, You can't do this, because here only first INSERT statement is part of FORALL. And hence you can only get the last value of sequence from CURRVAL. I would like to suggest you use FOR loop instead of FORALL.

Comment: yeah, I know that it doesn't work because of this reason. I tried to do BEGIN - END but it didn't work so I just paste it in order to get a general idea.

Comment: If you can provide the complete code for the specific block to your problem then might be I can help you out, put your code block where you are facing the issue.